# Report taking long to load - timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a SQL report (rdls) deployed on a report server, that we browse on Internet Explorer for example

We have is a result that returns a lot of records from SQL server, the size of data returned is 62 Mbs
so it takes long to load onto the report and it times out.

Is there any paging or caching tricks that we can try so that the report only loads the first few pages of data at a time while the rest of the data is cached somewhere? We also don't want to use parameters to limit the data on first load (business requirement)

any suggestions?

Comment: which report you talking about?

Comment: `Is there any [...] tricks [...] so that the report only loads the first few pages` =><= `We [...] don't want to use parameters to limit the data on first load` might be just me but this sounds contradicting to me or are you saying you want to limit the results on the first load but you just don't want to use parameters?

Comment: sorry, my first line was cut off. I will edit the question

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - bad wording perhaps. I would guess that they want to see first pages of unfiltered data or something.

Comment: No, the entire dataset is loaded before the report is generated. What you can do is to do manual paging. Add a `Page` report parameter which defaults to 1 and use it in the query. Add an action on the report which opens itself with `Page` = `Page` + 1.

Comment: Oh, that's disappointing. I thought there was a way to cache the data somewhere and and only access the "pages" you want as you page through the report front end. I like that Idea though, it would definitely work better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Top operator with some ID to order you data. **Top (10)** for example selects the first 10 rows for example.

Do something like:

```
Select Top (10) a, b...
from ...
where Id > i * 10
```

So the next call will be with increased i to get the next 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Begin INT = 100
DECLARE @End INT = 200

SELECT rp.RN, rp.Id, rp.SomeOtherColumn FROM
(
    SELECT 
        rp.Id, 
        rp.SomeOtherColumn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rp.Id) RN
    FROM MyReportTable rp
) rp
WHERE rp.RN >= @Begin AND rp.RN < @End
```

Now you can use begin and end to page the amount of data you want to get from the database and break it into chunks.